# Left shifting a register by one byte in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am a beginner at this. I am trying to left shift a register by one byte but it is not routing and I have no clue why.

The FPGA in question is the Lattice iCEstick.

```
reg [MSG_BUF_LEN*8-1:0] msg_data;
```

Case that does not route (left shift):

```
tx_byte <= msg_data[MSG_BUF_LEN*8-1:MSG_BUF_LEN*7];           
msg_data <= {msg_data[MSG_BUF_LEN*7-1:0], 8'd0};
```

The above lines work on their own but not when I put them together.

Case that works (right shift):

```
tx_byte <= msg_data[7:0];
msg_data <= {8'd0, msg_data[MSG_BUF_LEN*8-1:8]};
```

Output:

```
(DEBUG) Home_dir: /home/xtrinch/.apio
[Sat Oct 16 18:59:30 2021] Processing icestick
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
yosys -p "synth_ice40 -json hardware.json" -q top.v uart.v uart_comm.v
nextpnr-ice40 --hx1k --package tq144 --json hardware.json --asc hardware.asc --pcf 
icestick.pcf -q
ERROR: Failed to expand region (0, 0) |_> (13, 17) of 1314 ICESTORM_LCs
0 warnings, 1 error
scons: *** [hardware.asc] Error 255
```

I wish I knew what error 255 is also. Are the errors always that unhelpful?

Comment: @toolic Yeah sure here's the full repo and the file it can be found in: https://github.com/xtrinch/icestick-fpga-uart/blob/master/uart_comm.v#L151

Comment: `{msg_data[MSG_BUF_LEN*7-1:0]` now I don't do Verilog, but I got a feeling multiplying MSG_BUF_LEN by 7 **really** isn't what you wanted to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your array indexing is incorrect:

```
tx_byte <= msg_data[MSG_BUF_LEN*8-1:MSG_BUF_LEN*7];
msg_data <= {msg_data[MSG_BUF_LEN*7-1:0], 8'd0};
```

Both of those are multiplying by 7 not 8. You also need to subtract 1 from your `MSG_BUF_LEN` to get the correct offset.

Try:

```
tx_byte <= msg_data[MSG_BUF_LEN*8-1:(MSG_BUF_LEN-1)*8];           
msg_data <= {msg_data[(MSG_BUF_LEN-1)*8-1:0], 8'd0};
```

Or alternatively:

```
tx_byte <= msg_data[(MSG_BUF_LEN-1)*8 +: 8];           
msg_data <= {msg_data[0 +: (MSG_BUF_LEN-1)*8], 8'd0};
```

Comment: Wow what a stupid mistake there! Thx! You're absolutely right. But interestingly enough, it still does not route, same error :/ I used the first suggestion

Comment: Ow yeah ran out of luts, nothing else!